# Error pandas y matplotlib could not convert string to float

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy tratando de dibujar en un gráfica los precios de celular según sus modelos

Por ahora tengo esto

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df1 = pd.read_csv('MercadoLibreMejor_items.csv')
print(df1)


x = df1['Modelo']
y = df1['Precio']

#plot
plt.plot(x,y)


plt.show()
```

La lectura del `csv` es correcta pero al momento de dibujar la gráfica me tira el siguiente error:

> `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Pixi 3 (4)`

Creo que es porque en la columna de Modelo es un string pero no sabría como formatearla a `float`

Comment: Emanuel es por lo que comentas, espera que le pases puntos con sus coordenadas en los ejes.  ¿los datos son los del csv de tu otra pregunta? Es para crear un ejemplo en base a ellos.

Comment: Si, son los mismos datos

Comment: Emanuel mira la respuesta a ver que te parece, como comento no se si es el mejor tipo de gráfica para mostrar esto (puede que una de barra sea más descriptiva). Se le pueden añadir muchas cosas más si quieres como etiquetas a los ejes, líneas verticales y horizontales, cuadrícula, cambiar el color, agregar puntos en la linea con el precio exacto del modelo, etc. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si es la gráfica más descriptiva para mostrar esto, pero el problema es que, como es lógico, necesitas aportarle puntos con sus coordenadas ***x*** e ***y*** para obtener la gráfica. La solución es usar un rango de enteros desde 0 hasta el número de elementos que tengas (modelos de teléfonos en este caso) y usarlos para graficar.

Posteriormente cambiamos las marcas que debe mostrar el eje ***x*** para que muestre los nombres de los modelos. En este caso podemos usar el índice del dataframe como valor de ***x*** y el precio para ***y***.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.read_csv('MercadoLibreMejor_items.csv', sep = ';')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) 
x = df1.index
y = df1['Precio']

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(df1['Modelo'], rotation='vertical', fontsize=10)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es genial! Gracias !! Con esto ya tengo una idea mejor y probaré otros tipos de grafcas

Comment: @EmanuelCortez esta es la tercera pregunta con respuestas que tienes en el sitio (en donde además comentas que te fueron útiles). Por favor considera marcar como aceptadas aquellas respuestas a tus preguntas que consideres que son más útiles para resolver tu problema. Si no sabes como funciona la aceptación de respuestas mírate: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089. Un saludo.